# Can deleting files from a samba share locally cause problems with a clients connection?

Tags: linux, networking, network-shares, samba, sharing

Im having an issue with a rpi4 based samba share. When I SSH into the server and delete a file locally, the connection to my one and only client seems to become less than reliable. Files that the client tries to put on the server dissapear or files will be empty once on the server. If i dont SSH into the server and delete anything, everything seems to work fine. The client is a piece of industrial equipment that uses a kind of file based request/response system to communicate. You put a request file in the share and it puts a response file in the share you can then read. The only thing I know about the client is that it must use smb1 because I have to enable ntlm auth in my smb.conf file. Here is what I have in my smb.conf

[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
ntlm auth = yes

server role = standalone server

[E63Session]
comment = E63Session
path = /home/pi/E63Session
browsable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777

Ive tried enabling and disabling many settings in the smb.conf file with no effect. If try doing the same thing with windows 10 with the smb1 feature turned on I have no issue. Just on the rpi4.
Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds very much as if the client assumes it is the ONLY device that accesses the folder and that nothing else ever accesses/modifies anything.
It probably reads the directory on the share once on startup and then proceeds to use it without any error-checking or re-reading to see if anything has changed. As soon as you remove a file from the folder the directory contents has changed, but the client doesn't know that leading to errors, retries and corrupted files/folders.
(Run a fsck on the filesystem please, if you haven't done this already... You may have a corrupted filesystem as well.)

That sounds like a real stupid thing to do, but it is not unheard off, especially on old industrial systems.
In many cases these were originally designed to work with an internal disk (that no one else could access) and later got network ability added, but the fundamental single-user logic of its file-handling was never modernized to support multi-user access.

There is no real way around that. To be safe you can't do anything with that share and its contents while the industrial system is also using it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tonny. I would agree with your assesment of the client, but if I set the share up on a Windows box I am able to delete files from the share locally with out breaking the clients connection. It just seems like the client doesnt like some part of the samba setup, but im at a  loss as to what that could be.

Comment: @Riggs It could be. We occasionally have some strange issues with Samba shares on Linux as well. And I've seen some weird behavior between MacOS and Windows too. (Even asked a question about that here too.) Apparently SMB implementations are not as compatible with other implementations as we would like.